# Sorting the leafs of multiple partition (sunburst) charts independently

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm attempting to create multiple partition (sunburst) charts on a page - one partition view for each category value existing for each item. Unfortunately, I'm running into an issue where the 'leaf' nodes of these hierarchies are not sorting independently, it seems that they only sort based on the 'last' chart used.

I am defining the layout with:

```
  var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius])
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });
```

Then using this layout on each item of an array, to draw each as a sunburst.

See working example here: http://tributary.io/inlet/9598331
(you can see by hovering over the leaf nodes that the nodes exist in the same order on each chart.  This is not as it is intended, or correct, in the group hierarchy.)

[image: visual of problem]

I've tried several things, like creating an array of hierarchy layouts, changing the `.sort` function of the layout, etc.., but have not been able to make progress in troubleshooting.  I suspect that there is something very simple I am missing here, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around the problem.  Any help is appreciated!